# Размер фонового изображения в css

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, с фоном.

```
.slide {
    background-image: url("../img/slide.jpg");
    height: 476px;
    background-position: 50%50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

А можно тут указать размер этого изображение? Хочу под каждое расширение экрана что бы сжималось, а то придеться делать много картинок под каждоме расширение.

Comment: **background-size:cover;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте:

```
.slide {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
```

или

```
.slide {
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
}
```

Пример с `cover`:

```css
.slide {
    background-image: url("http://www.randrs.ru/photo/1-0/903_bumblebee-.jpg");
      height: 476px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide"></div>
```

Пример с `contain`:

```css
.slide {
    background-image: url("http://www.randrs.ru/photo/1-0/903_bumblebee-.jpg");
      height: 476px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
     background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide"></div>
```